# $index of ng-repeat inside the attribute (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

That's must be very simple,but: have this HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="title in mainTree">
      <a href="#cable{{$index}}">{{title.title}}</a>
</li>
```

JS tells me, that **caught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #cable{{$index}}** 
However, I'd like to enumerate my pseudolinks by this way.

UPD:

```
var cableFiltersApp = angular.module('cableFiltersApp', []);
cableFiltersApp.controller('cableFormAngularController', function CableFormsListCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.mainTree = [
  {
    "title" : "Кабель алюминиевый", "subNodes": [
                                                  "АКВВГэ,АКВВГэнг",
                                                  "Кабель ААБ2л",
                                                  "Кабель ААБл",
                                                  "Кабель ААШв",
                                                  "Кабель АВБбШВ",
                                                  "Кабель АВВГ",
                                                  "Кабель АВВГнг,АВВГнгд",
                                                  "Кабель АКВБбШВ,АКВБбШнг",
                                                  "Кабель АКВВГ,АКВВГнг",
                                                  "Кабель АСБ",
                                                  "Кабель АСБл",
                                                  "Кабель ЦААБл"
                                                  ]
  }]
```

It returns me this:

[image]

but the fix is using the **ng-href** directive

Comment: It seems to work fine for me ([plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/shE78RLwGFuEdZdWaNA1?p=preview)). Post some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hm, that's really strange: advice at the first comment works and your example too.

Comment: suggestion...avoid using `$index` in repeaters. Will find out the hard way the minute you start any filtering that `$index` is only the index of filtered array...not original. Then if you try changing properties based on `$index` will update wrong object